# Magento 1.9 module oddly breaking when changing resource folder from Mysql4 to Resource

Tags: magento-1.9, module, resources

It's a fresh 1.9 installation. I'm new, so I was following some guides which turned out to be outdated, and so I used Mysql4 classes instead of Resource.

I changed the extensions from `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract` to `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`, and they worked perfectly.

I then tried to change the name of the model/resource folder from `Mysql4` to `Resource`.

I changed its name in the `config.xml` from `<class>Foo_Foobar_Model_Mysql4</class>` to `<class>Foo_Foobar_Model_Resource</class>`, and the class names of the resources from

`class Foo_Foobar_Model_Mysql4_Example`
To 
`class Foo_Foobar_Model_Resource_Example`.

But for some reason, the last two steps broke the module, and I started getting:

`Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Foo_Foobar_Model_Resource_Example.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94`

Even though the class is right there.. I tried checking the permissions and owners of the files on the server, and they're exactly the same in both cases.. What is the cause for this weird error.. Everything is the same except the folder name..

Comment: You need to disable the compilation and reenable it again.

Comment: I tried that.. The module is just giving a blank page now..

Comment: Or click rebuild compilation

Comment: Yes, I had to clear the compilation and now it works great. Thank you! If you want post it as an answer so I can select a right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable or rebuild compilation.

Thanks to Marius too!