# Why does my module getting warrning "Mysql4 classes are obsolete "

Tags: magento-1.9, best-practice, coding-standards, magento-ecg

Hello i have create custom module and getting warning **Mysql4 classes are obsolete**

```
class Mymodule_Custom_Model_Mysql4_Stores extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{    
    public function _construct()
    {  
        $this->_init('custom/stores', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

getting warning on line number 2

Comment: I have already accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mysql4` models still work, but with 1.7 `Resocure` models were introduced ... so you'll get a notification, when running codesniffer ...

Guess you'll find complete answer here:

- [How to handle deprecated "Mysql4" classes when rewriting resource models](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/how-to-handle-deprecated-mysql4-classes-when-rewriting-resource-models)
- [Magento 1.9 module oddly breaking when changing resource folder from Mysql4 to Resource](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60351/magento-1-9-module-oddly-breaking-when-changing-resource-folder-from-mysql4-to-r)