# Why do the Magento 1 setup scripts still have to be prefixed with 'mysql4'?

Tags: magento-1, setup-script

MySQL4 is largely obsolete now, even [Magento 1 latest versions send a warning if you use Mysql4 prefixed classes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178898/why-does-my-module-getting-warrning-mysql4-classes-are-obsolete). I searched if the setup file names also had this deprecation but couldn't find a thing.

Is this a choice from the Magento team and is there a reason behind it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They dont need them

https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Create the installation file app/code/community/Inchoo/DBScript/sql/inchoo_dbscript_setup/install-3.1.5.6.php with the content like shown below.

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('inchoo_dbscript/ticket'))
    ->addColumn('ticket_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Title')
    ->addColumn('description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Description');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('inchoo_dbscript/comment'))
    ->addColumn('comment_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('comment', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Comment');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Or are you saying why no warning? Warning on file names is harder to scan for than class names